# How can I disable firebug in my webpage?

Tags: javascript

How can I disable firebug using Javascript? I want to do this to hide the workings of my webpage from visitors. Is there any option to do this?

Comment: But your visitors will still be able to do http://your.website.user/scripts/yourawesomescript.js ?

Comment: You can't hide your workings. So do those working properly so that there is nothing to be ashamed of :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. The best you can do is obfuscate your JavaScript.

Actually scratch that. The best you can do is move all the security-critical code to the server. You should be doing that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) on different methods others have adopted as a work around of sorts

Answer (score 1):

As Amadan said, you can't disable particular source-viewers.

But you can use a hack. It works only with viewers, that add them selves to the DOM. You just have to delete specified node. Did a look-around with Firebug Lite for Chrome.
DON'T use this approach, only for fun :)